# I have exception with CrudRepository: DbActionExecutionException: Failed to execute DbAction.UpdateRoot(...))

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-jdbc, crud-repository

```
@SpringBootTest
class UserRepositoryTest {
    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    public UserRepositoryTest(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }


    @Test
    void test() {
        User user = new User("test", "test", "test@gmail.com");
        userRepository.save(user);
    }
}
```

```
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.Email;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotEmpty;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Persistable;
import org.springframework.data.relational.core.mapping.Table;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table("users")
@Entity
public class User implements UserDetails, Persistable<String> {
    @Id
    @NotEmpty(message = "Username is empty!")
    private String username;
    @NotEmpty(message = "Password is empty!")
    private String password;
    @NotEmpty(message = "Email is empty!")
    @Email(message = "Email isn't valid")
    private String email;

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return List.of(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String getId() {
        return getUsername();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isNew() {
        return getId() == null;
    }
}
```

```
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(excludeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, value = {UserRepository.class}))
@Configuration
public class DataConfig {
}
```

```
import com.w4t3rcs.todolist.model.entity.User;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, String> {
}
```

And there is the stacktrace: org.springframework.data.relational.core.conversion.DbActionExecutionException: Failed to execute DbAction.UpdateRoot(entity=User(username=test, password=$2a$10$jbNHYFBd9AGD8LVtXyej4.7paMKX30IjZryMCsKs3xyhfIsbF0KXC, email=test@gmail.com))

```
at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.AggregateChangeExecutor.execute(AggregateChangeExecutor.java:118)
at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.AggregateChangeExecutor.lambda$executeSave$0(AggregateChangeExecutor.java:61)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
at org.springframework.data.relational.core.conversion.SaveBatchingAggregateChange.forEachAction(SaveBatchingAggregateChange.java:70)
at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.AggregateChangeExecutor.executeSave(AggregateChangeExecutor.java:61)
at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.JdbcAggregateTemplate.performSave(JdbcAggregateTemplate.java:491)
at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.JdbcAggregateTemplate.save(JdbcAggregateTemplate.java:168)
at org.springframework.data.jdbc.repository.support.SimpleJdbcRepository.save(SimpleJdbcRepository.java:68)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:352)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker$RepositoryFragmentMethodInvoker.lambda$new$0(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:277)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:170)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:158)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:516)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:285)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:628)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:168)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:143)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:385)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:249)
at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy115.save(Unknown Source)
at com.w4t3rcs.todolist.UserRepositoryTest.test(UserRepositoryTest.java:26)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
```

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Required identifier property not found for class com.w4t3rcs.todolist.model.entity.User
at org.springframework.data.mapping.PersistentEntity.getRequiredIdProperty(PersistentEntity.java:135)
at org.springframework.data.relational.core.mapping.BasicRelationalPersistentEntity.getIdColumn(BasicRelationalPersistentEntity.java:159)
at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.convert.SqlContext.getIdColumn(SqlContext.java:44)
at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.convert.SqlGenerator.getIdColumn(SqlGenerator.java:807)
at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.convert.SqlGenerator.createBaseUpdate(SqlGenerator.java:718)
at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.convert.SqlGenerator.createUpdateSql(SqlGenerator.java:692)
at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:135)
at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:113)
at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.convert.SqlGenerator.getUpdate(SqlGenerator.java:369)
at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.convert.DefaultDataAccessStrategy.update(DefaultDataAccessStrategy.java:136)
at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.JdbcAggregateChangeExecutionContext.updateWithoutVersion(JdbcAggregateChangeExecutionContext.java:336)
at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.JdbcAggregateChangeExecutionContext.executeUpdateRoot(JdbcAggregateChangeExecutionContext.java:129)
at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.AggregateChangeExecutor.execute(AggregateChangeExecutor.java:93)
... 36 more

I've tried making @Id type of Long and tried changing some annotations, but nothing couldn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `Entity` I see some miss configurations to fix it just change current one with next one:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "users")
@Entity
public class User implements UserDetails {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;


  @NotEmpty(message = "Username is empty!")
  @Column(unique = true)
  private String username;

  @NotEmpty(message = "Password is empty!")
  private String password;

  @NotEmpty(message = "Email is empty!")
  @Email(message = "Email isn't valid")
  @Column(unique = true)
  private String email;

  @Override
  public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
    return List.of(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isEnabled() {
    return true;
  }
}
```

And also I did some changes about `Entity` I think that `username` and `email` should be `UNIQUE`.

Also I think that you dont need to `implements Persistable interface`.

All above information/changes should fix your problem

Comment: If my answer was helpfully don’t forget to accept it and also upvote for future if someone will have the same problem as you.